# Doing a CASE WHEN EXISTS where all values must exist

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new here so please bear with me while I try and explain the problem.

I am writing a script for members of my team that have SQL access to try and make things easier, however I am coming across a problem.

The problem occurs when I make a `CASE WHEN EXISTS` within a select statement within the following script:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table1.id IN  ('96','100') )
THEN "YES" ELSE "NO" END AS "Entitlements"
```

The problem occurs because the ID in table1 can exist more than once in table2, and I am trying to get the script to say Yes when `ALL` values in table have been met, but using an `IN ('96','100')` is effectively an `OR` statement so it only has to exist once in that table for it to say YES.

How do I get it to say Yes when `ALL` the values have been met and then display the values that are missing when it is `NOT` met, I am fully prepared to have two fields, one for when they all exist and one to show all values that are not met.

Also, there could be up to 32 different values listed in due course so some of `DECLARE` in the statement will be used at a later date but I hope this gives a good outline as to what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: "Yes when ALL values in table have been met" did you mean table1? and please do try not to use table names like table1, table2 it's rather confusing and leads to hard to maintain systems.

Comment: My apologies, I will try and explain a bit better, yes I meant table1, I don't want to give proper table names at this point as it would be against our company policy to do so *sigh*, however you are correct in that I want it to show if all the ID's from table1 exist then it displays Complete, however if one of them is missing then to show the ID of the one that is missing.

Comment: Can I assume then that there is no answer to this question? It would really help me out if someone would point me in the direction of what I am looking for.

Thanks